# AC voltage measurement upto 230V AC

Tags: voltage, ac

How can I effectively measure up to 230 v AC using a PIC micro controller? 
I just want to measure Line voltage, and as per the measurement I need to apply in the design.

Comment: Have you read: https://learn.openenergymonitor.org/electricity-monitoring/voltage-sensing/measuring-voltage-with-an-acac-power-adapter ?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie: The problem with those is that you never know how bad they distort the waveform, or how much they filter out interesting information.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I fully agree with what you say. My approach to this is safety first since we're dealing with mains voltage here and perhaps OP doesn't realize how to measure mains voltage safely. If the solution from the link is not good enough due to the reasons you mention then there are other solutions of course.

Comment: I have done so with a AD202KN analog isolator and a AD736 RMS to DC converter, but that alone is $30 USD so far. Precision measurements are a bit absurd because the PIC only has 10 bits of resolution, or 1 out of 1024 levels. Equal to 000 to 999.

Answer (score 1):

Look up something called a *voltage divider*.  That is two resistors that scale down a input voltage linearly.  To get 3.0 V from 230 V, for example, you need one that scales the input down by about 77.

If you want to measure the negative parts of the waveform too, then you have to use three resistors.  Such a setup attenuates and adds a offset at the same time.

There are other issues, like power isolation, but those have also been covered extensively here and many other places.